# webpack compilation sass error: Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"

Tags: webpack, mean-stack

I'm currently learning webpack and MEAN stack. I need to load my scss file to my project, and I'm using extract-text-webpack-plugin and the css-loader and sass-loader in my webpack.common.js file. It successfully converts the scss file to css and it loads it to the folder '/dist/' where my project is built. However, I'm getting an error in when running webpack:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"id":1,"omit":1,"remove":true}!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/
sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed:
// html, body{
^
      Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in C:\Users\Andres\Source\Repos\mean\mean\src\app\app.component.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./src/app/app.component.scss 2:21-330
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
```

This is the webpack.common.js file, I'm working with (with it consists on pretty much the webpack.common.js file provided by [mean.io](http://mean.io/) to start your mean app with some minor changes I made):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineManifestWebpackPlugin = require('inline-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const ngcWebpack = require('ngc-webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
//const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const AOT = process.env.BUILD_AOT || helpers.hasNpmFlag('aot');
const METADATA = {
  title: 'TEST',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer(),
  HMR: HMR
};
var extractTextPlugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: './assets/css/site.css'
});

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function (options) {
  isProd = options.env === 'production';
  return {

    /**
     * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
     * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
     * You can pass false to disable it.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
     */
    //cache: false,

    /**
     * The entry point for the bundle
     * Our Angular.js app
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    entry: {

      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
      'main': AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
        './src/main.browser.ts',
      'app': './src/assets/scripts/app.js'

    },

    /**
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {

      /**
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

      /**
       * An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
       */
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), helpers.root('node_modules')],

    },

    /**
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {
      loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }],

      rules: [

        /**
         * Typescript loader support for .ts
         *
         * Component Template/Style integration using `angular2-template-loader`
         * Angular 2 lazy loading (async routes) via `ng-router-loader`
         *
         * `ng-router-loader` expects vanilla JavaScript code, not TypeScript code. This is why the
         * order of the loader matter.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
         * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
         * See: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/ng-router-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
              options: {
                pretty: !isProd,
                prod: isProd
              }
            },
            {
              /**
               *  MAKE SURE TO CHAIN VANILLA JS CODE, I.E. TS COMPILATION OUTPUT.
               */
              loader: 'ng-router-loader',
              options: {
                loader: 'async-import',
                genDir: 'compiled',
                aot: AOT
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
              options: {
                configFileName: 'tsconfig.webpack.json',
                useCache: !isProd,
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
            }
          ],
          exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },

        /**
         * Json loader support for *.json files.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader'
        },

        /**
         * To string and css loader support for *.css files (from Angular components)
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /**
         * To string and sass loader support for *.scss files (from Angular components)
         * Returns compiled css content as string
         *
         */
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
        },

        /**
         * Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },

        /**
         * File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
         */
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },

        /* File loader for supporting fonts, for example, in CSS files.
        */
        {
          test: /\.(eot|woff2?|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: extractTextPlugin.extract({
            fallback: "style-loader",
            loader: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          })
        },


      ],

    },

    /**
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [
      // Use for DLLs
      // new AssetsPlugin({
      //   path: helpers.root('dist'),
      //   filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
      //   prettyPrint: true
      // }),

      /**
       * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
       * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
       */
      new CheckerPlugin(),
      /**
       * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
       * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
       * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
       */
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'polyfills',
        chunks: ['polyfills']
      }),
      /**
       * This enables tree shaking of the vendor modules
       */
      // new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      //   name: 'vendor',
      //   chunks: ['main'],
      //   minChunks: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource)
      // }),
      /**
       * Specify the correct order the scripts will be injected in
       */
      // new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      //   name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
      // }),
      // new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      //   name: ['manifest'],
      //   minChunks: Infinity,
      // }),

      /**
       * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
       * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
       * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
       */
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /**
         * The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
         */
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
        helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
        {
          /**
           * Your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root directory
           */
        }
      ),

      /**
       * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
       *
       * Copies project static assets.
       *
       * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
       */
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
        { from: 'src/meta' }
      ],
        { ignore: ['*.scss'] },
        isProd ? { ignore: ['mock-data/**/*'] } : undefined
      ),

      /*
       * Plugin: PreloadWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Preload is a web standard aimed at improving
       * performance and granular loading of resources.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/preload-webpack-plugin
       */
      //new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      //  rel: 'preload',
      //  as: 'script',
      //  include: ['polyfills', 'vendor', 'main'].reverse(),
      //  fileBlacklist: ['.css', '.map']
      //}),
      //new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      //  rel: 'prefetch',
      //  as: 'script',
      //  include: 'asyncChunks'
      //}),

      /**
       * Plugin: ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin
       * Description: Enhances html-webpack-plugin functionality
       * with different deployment options for your scripts including:
       *
       * See: https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin
       */
      new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
        sync: /polyfill|vendor/,
        defaultAttribute: 'async',
        preload: [/polyfill|vendor|main/],
        prefetch: [/chunk/]
      }),

      /*
      * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
      * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
      * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
      * which changes every compilation.
      *
      * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      */
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        title: METADATA.title,
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
        metadata: METADATA,
        inject: 'body'
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: HtmlElementsPlugin
       * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
       *
       * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
       * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
       * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
       *
       * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
       * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
       *
       * Example:
       *  Adding this plugin configuration
       *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
       *    headTags: { ... }
       *  })
       *
       *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
       *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
       *
       * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
       */
      new HtmlElementsPlugin({
        headTags: require('./head-config.common')
      }),

      extractTextPlugin,

      /**
       * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
       *
       * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
       */
      new LoaderOptionsPlugin({}),

      new ngcWebpack.NgcWebpackPlugin({
        /**
         * If false the plugin is a ghost, it will not perform any action.
         * This property can be used to trigger AOT on/off depending on your build target (prod, staging etc...)
         *
         * The state can not change after initializing the plugin.
         * @default true
         */
        disabled: !AOT,
        tsConfig: helpers.root('tsconfig.webpack.json'),
        /**
         * A path to a file (resource) that will replace all resource referenced in @Components.
         * For each `@Component` the AOT compiler compiles it creates new representation for the templates (html, styles)
         * of that `@Components`. It means that there is no need for the source templates, they take a lot of
         * space and they will be replaced by the content of this resource.
         *
         * To leave the template as is set to a falsy value (the default).
         *
         * TIP: Use an empty file as an overriding resource. It is recommended to use a ".js" file which
         * usually has small amount of loaders hence less performance impact.
         *
         * > This feature is doing NormalModuleReplacementPlugin for AOT compiled resources.
         *
         * ### resourceOverride and assets
         * If you reference assets in your styles/html that are not inlined and you expect a loader (e.g. url-loader)
         * to copy them, don't use the `resourceOverride` feature as it does not support this feature at the moment.
         * With `resourceOverride` the end result is that webpack will replace the asset with an href to the public
         * assets folder but it will not copy the files. This happens because the replacement is done in the AOT compilation
         * phase but in the bundling it won't happen (it's being replaced with and empty file...)
         *
         * @default undefined
         */
        resourceOverride: helpers.root('config/resource-override.js')
      }),

      /**
       * Plugin: InlineManifestWebpackPlugin
       * Inline Webpack's manifest.js in index.html
       *
       * https://github.com/szrenwei/inline-manifest-webpack-plugin
       */
      new InlineManifestWebpackPlugin(),
    ],

    /**
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: true,
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: true,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, but it seems that I can't figure out a solution for it.

Has anyone faced the same issue before?

**Update**

My app.component.scss file is all commented out:

```
// html, body{
//   height: 100%;
//   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
// header{
//   background-color: primary
// }
// .example-fill-remaining-space {
//   // This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox. 
//   // Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout.
//   flex: 2 2 auto;
// }
// header{
//   width:100%;

// .logotTxt{
//   color: white; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1; text-align: center;
//   padding: 15px;

// }
// .links
// {
//     color: white; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight:initial; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1; text-align: center; 
//     padding: 15px;

// }
// }
// }
```

In fact, I don't even need to use app.component.scss because I'm planning to have all my stylesheet in one file and not one per each component.

Answer (score 2):

In your web.config.js remove the rules for test for scss and sass and add

```
{
    test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
        options: {
          implementation: require('sass'),
          fiber: require('fibers'),
          indentedSyntax: true // optional
        },
        // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
        options: {
          implementation: require('sass'),
          sassOptions: {
            fiber: require('fibers'),
            indentedSyntax: true // optional
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Where should i make this change?

Comment: In the webpack config

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by simply not using the sass loader for all the  *.scss files from the Angular components due to I'm using only .scss to style all components